# Local database vs Server database in Android Development

Tags: android

What are the differences between a local database and a server database?

Comment: I understand, but my question was mostly referred to Android development. Why are some people using local database when the data basically is not saved on a server for the user to be able to login on another device? Is it really able to later send the data to a server in the background? Or should the login be connected directly to a server when a user logins or register? I need to know why one is better than the other and why is a local server is even used in android applications?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Please define "None if better". In my case, I'm talking about an application having around 10k users where they are able to create accounts and later be able to insert image and text into a database to share it publicly for the other logged in users to see.
How come none is better? What do **you** recommend otherwise for an application like mentioned?

Comment: *I'm talking about an application having around 10k users where they are able to create accounts and later be able to insert image and text into a database to share it publicly for the other logged in users to see.* well you should have said that in the question. In that case, server database is the only option

Comment: Sidenote, we are not interested in the background of your question. Keep it short and simple. Reading takes time, and reading irrelevant info is a waste of time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you know the basic answer:

-Local Database: the database is located on the User's Android Device.

-Server Database: the User's Android Device must connect to an external server to access the database.

Here is my real world example of my usages of both:

I was tasked to develop an app for "Secret Shoppers" employed by Sam's Club. Basically they had to go to different grocery stores, and report prices using the app, and that data must be saved in Sam's Clubs Databases (On THEIR Servers). Here was 'the catch', not every Secret Shopper had a tablet with a 4g network, thus could only transfer the data while they were on WiFi.

So what I did was create an exact clone of their databases using SQLite, every time they 'submitted' a report of products and prices:

1. First I checked that the User's Android Device had internet access.
2. If they DID HAVE internet at the time of submitting, the report would be sent to Sam's Club servers as normal.
3. If they DID NOT HAVE internet at the time of submitting, the report would ONLY save on the LOCAL Database on the Android Device with a FLAG indicating it has not been sent to Sam's Club Servers.
4. When the app is run with internet, it will then send the those flagged reports to Sam's Club Servers.

So basically, I used a LOCAL Database that SYNCS with a SERVER Database each time the app is run. Hope this helps with the 'picture' you are looking for in terms of Local vs Server in Android Development specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Local database would be SQLite in android. It can be accessed locally only.

A server database is hosted in a remote server. Basically It can be accessed by any client in the web.

An example of local use would be for example storing credentials or information that you don't want/need to share with another user.

You can use local database to create a backup of the server database in order to access your information even if you don't have a reliable internet connection o make your app faster by not downloading data every single time you need it and using the one store locally.

For example Facebook is saving everything in a server database so you and millions people around the world can accesses to that information.

Comment: I'll bet you that Facebook also has a local database

Comment: I'm explaining why Facebook uses server databases not that Facebook doesn't use local databases.

Answer (score -2):

The local database is Local (offline) & the server database is online

This is the biggest difference, It all depends on your app style

If you want a dynamic application you should use online database

else

you can use both of them for static data